# Add items to dropdownlist with javascript and persist in postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm pretty new to web development, and I've encountered the following problem I don't really understand. Working in VS2010 with visual basic.

I have a page (aspx), which has a gridview, and this has a few columns, including a column with tickboxes and a column 'action', which has an empty, hidden dropdownlist to begin with (every row has this).

Whenever a user ticks a box, I retrieve some values from the server with an AJAX-call (which is my first attempt at AJAX :-)) and with those values I populate a dropdownlist in the 'action' colum of the selected row. So far so good.

The user can then make a selection on the dropdownlist, en then he presses a button (upload), and a postback is done to process the information.

However, in the code behind, I can't retrieve the added items in the dropdownlist (let alone the selected value). I CAN retrieve the dropdownlist, but it has no items.

After googling for some time I realised that client-side changes are not persisted when the form is posted to the server, which I understand- but it also seems odd. The dropdown is created when the page is created, so why doesn't it store the javascipt-added items? Especially since a few work-arounds I found use a hiddenfield to store the added items or selectedvalue. If I can store them in a hiddenfield, why can't I store them in the actual dropdownlist?

I'm obviously not understanding how websites work... But this means that, after a page is initially loaded, you can change values in dropdowns and listboxes and such, but these will never be available serverside?

Edit: some code; the first a javascript-snippet how I add the different values I retrieved through the AJAX call:

```
var drop = row.findElement("ddlAction"); //find the dropdownelement in the DOM
for (j = 0; j < dropdownitems.length; j++) { //add all the options from xml
     option = document.createElement("option");
     option.text = dropdownitems[i].getAttribute("text");
     option.value = dropdownitems[i].getAttribute("value");
     drop.add(option, null);
}
```

This works fine, the dropdownlist is filled and I can select. But when the page gets posted I do the following in the server code:

```
Dim SelCount As Integer = LocalFilesGrid.SelectedItems.Count
If SelCount >= 0 Then
   For Each dataItem In LocalFilesGrid.SelectedItems
       Dim drop As DropDownList
       drop = dataItem.FindControl("ddlAction")
       If drop.Items.Count = 0 Then 'always zero
          MsgBox("Nope")
       End If
   Next
End If
```

I'd like to be able to loop through the selected rows of the grid, get the corresponding dropdownlist and selectedvalue.

Comment: SOF folks will be more interested to see the `code please` :)

Answer (score 1):

When you mix such different technologies you will end up in troubles like this. What you are trying to do is bit of `Ajax` and a bit of `ASP.NET`. Choose one and then use it. If you choose `ASP.NET` instead of `AJAX` call use `UpdatePanel` which will simplify your life.

If you want to `Ajax` stuff your self, then handle the button click and submit the request by ajax rather than postback.

The reason why you are able to retrieve the drop down but not the items because you must have declared the drop down in aspx but the items were added on client side, so server has no knowledge about the items.

The reason is `ASP.NET` uses view state and you can not mess with view state. So you can add the data to hidden field and read them at server but you can not write the data in view state.

The best way is use `ASP.NET` with `UpdatePanels`. If you mix, then you will have to keep doing some sort of trick at every step. If you want to do your own Ajax stuff better use `MVC` and `Razor`(not mvc with aspx) because it is made for such use.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'll look into UpdatePanel.